# bash: existing file not existing - or existing? or not?

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I have an issue, that I can't fix, and I hope, I get some help here.

In a directory named `qemu-servers` should be a file named `100.conf`. But, bash does not show it, but if I test it, it's there...

```
root@proxmox:/etc/pve/nodes/proxmox/qemu-server# test 100.conf && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
Found
```

If I do `ls -a` it's not shown:

```
root@proxmox:/etc/pve/nodes/proxmox/qemu-server# ls -a
.  ..  101.conf
```

there is a file named `101.conf`, but not `100.conf`

If I try to `rm` the `100.conf`, `touch` it or anything else, bash gives back an error:

```
root@proxmox:/etc/pve/nodes/proxmox/qemu-server# rm 100.conf
rm: cannot remove ‘100.conf’: No such file or directory
root@proxmox:/etc/pve/nodes/proxmox/qemu-server# touch 100.conf
touch: cannot touch ‘100.conf’: File exists
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to work as 'root'?  You should avoid this as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
test 100.conf
```

it is doing a string test i.e. if the string `100.conf` is not empty. As it is not empty, you'll always get `Found`.

This is analogous to:

```
test -n 100.conf
[ 100.conf ]
[ -n 100.conf ]
```

---

You need the file existence check i.e. `test -f`:

```
test -f 100.conf && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
```